# SQL string aggregation based on a group by

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a dataset of INT, varchar. The ints can be grouped into small sets of 1 to 5, and I want to see the count of all the corresponding texts. E.g. input table (apols for format)

```
 1,a
 2,a
 2,b
 3,a
 3,q 
 3,z
 4,a
```

I can group by the Int, but have no idea how I can concat across rows. In the above i would want to know counts of:

```
a,2
ab,1
aqz,1
```

Can I do this purely in SQL, ideally in a generic db agnostic way?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: I was hoping for db agnostic, but it is some form of Sybase run at arms length - may be Sybase IQ

Comment: which Sybase product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version?  each product has its own set of functions that may (not) be sufficient for what you're looking to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sybase supports the [`LIST()`](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1604/doc/html/jcu1290709667623.html) function.  So:

```
select chrs, count(*) as cnt
from (select t.number, list(t.chr, '' order by t.chr) as chrs
      from t
      group by t.number
     ) n
group by chrs
order by count(*) desc;
```

Comment: Really appreciated. Maybe I dig deeper into db specific queries - that looks powerful!

Answer (score 3):

If you're using MySQL, you can use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to concatenate the characters into strings for each integer value, then `COUNT` the occurrences of each string:

```
SELECT str, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(str ORDER BY str SEPARATOR '') AS str
      FROM data
      GROUP BY i) d
GROUP BY str 
ORDER BY str
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e03f28/4)

In Oracle you can use [`LISTAGG`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030):

```
SELECT str, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM (SELECT LISTAGG(str, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY str) AS str
      FROM data
      GROUP BY i) d
GROUP BY str 
ORDER BY str
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8dddc/2)

In SQL Server 2017 and above you can use [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
SELECT str, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM (SELECT STRING_AGG(str, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY str) AS str
      FROM data
      GROUP BY i) d
GROUP BY str 
ORDER BY str
```

[Demo on SQLFIddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e03f2/1)

In PostgreSQL you can also use [`STRING_AGG`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-aggregate.html):

```
SELECT str, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM (SELECT STRING_AGG(str, '' ORDER BY str) AS str
      FROM data
      GROUP BY i) d
GROUP BY str 
ORDER BY str
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e03f28/5)

In all cases the output is:

```
STR     COUNT
a       2
ab      1
aqz     1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do by using `string_agg()` in SQL Server. check demo here [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a0fe4/4)

```
select 
  cnct_str, 
  count(*) as count
from
(
    select 
        string_agg(chars, '') within group (order by chars) as cnct_str
    from tabs
    group by id
) val
group by cnct_str
```